# Conditional mathematical expression

Tags: equation-solving, conditional

I want to produce **A, B, C, D and E** values between **0** and **2*pi** with two conditions:

```
 `A!=B!=C!=D!=E`
```

And

```
(C,D,E)!=n*pi/2
```

n is an integer
How do I do that in Mathematica without the use of Random number generator?

Comment: Make that `a, b, c, d, e` as the last three of these uppercase symbols have pre-defined usage in Mathematica. Then use: `{a, b, c, d, e} = RandomReal[{0, 2 \[Pi]}, 5]` for your first condition. I don't understand the second condition, so please explain what `n` is.

Comment: @Syed, n is any integer. In this case , (C,D,E) can't be 0, pi/2, 3pi/2, pi, 2pi. so n here is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Comment: Consider the output of `Subdivide[0, 2 \[Pi], 4]`. Five equally spaced numbers in the specified interval; each of which is not allowed.

Comment: Yes, these values are not allowed for C,D and E. But I am unable to find a way to use this condition along with the 1st one

Comment: If these numbers are not random then, by definition, you can specify how these are related. What is the generating function for these numbers? I would say that the question is not well-formed yet.

Comment: @Syed, Suppose I am generating x an y. {x, y} = {RandomReal[{0, 2*\[Pi]}], RandomReal[{0, 2*\[Pi]}]}; While[
 x != y && x < 2*\[Pi] && y < 2*\[Pi], Print[x]; Print[y]; x++ && y++]  The problem here is the increment. it is increasing with 1. can I decrease the step size?

Comment: Just discard those random numbers not meeting your criteria?

Answer (score 4):

One way is as follows.

```
FindInstance[{a, b, c, d, e} > 0 && {a, b, c, d, e} < 2*Pi && a != b &&
a != c && a != d && a != e && b != c && b != d && b != e && 
c != d && c != e &&  d != e && {a, b, c, d, e, d} != E && {c, d, e} !=Pi/2 && 
{c, d, e} != Pi && {c, d, e} != 3*Pi/2, {a, b, c, d, e}, Reals, 3]
```

> `{{a -> 205/48, b -> 79/17, c -> 1152/269, d -> 36956/8637,  e -> 27/8}, {a -> 1/6, b -> 51/607, c -> 183/1223, d -> 89/17,  e -> 545/97}, {a -> 113/48, b -> 12/43, c -> 63/362, d -> 68/581,  e -> 44/863}}`

Your conditions " between 0 and 2*pi " and "`A!=B!=C!=D!=E`" and "`(C,D,E)!=n*pi/2`" are unclearly formulated: are $0$ and $2\pi$ included? is $A\neq C$? what does $n$ denote?

Comment: n is an integer. Yes, A is not equal to C. and NO, 0 and 2*pi are not included

Answer (score 4):

Choose an integer that is not a multiple of 2 and is larger than 5, e.g.: n=7. Then divide 2Pi through this number:

```
t = 2 Pi/7
```

[image]

Now choose a..e as 1,2,3,4,5 times this number:

```
   {a,b,c,d,e}= t Range[5]
```

[image]

There are no two equal elements and no element is a multiple of 2.

Comment: This is done rather by hand than automatically and programmatically.

Comment: @user64494 Very clever